# how to declare dependency version in one place for many gradle projects

Tags: maven, gradle, grails, groovy, gradle-plugin

I work on a project with multiple grails services, plugins and libraries, all built with gradle with their dependencies declared in `build.gradle` files, one per project, this makes sense, I hope.

In maven I used to be able to declare versions of all dependencies in one parent project pom, or a pom template, and only include the dependencies in the projects that required them without the versions. This made upgrading dependencies easy in one place. Is there a simple way to do this in gradle?

Pseudocode example:

#### master_template/build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
        joda-time:joda-time:2.9.1
        cglib:cglib:3.2.9
        javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0
    }
```

#### service_a/build.gradle

```
    parent: master_template
    dependencies {
        joda-time:joda-time
        javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api
    }
```

#### service_b/build.gradle

```
    parent: master_template
    dependencies {
        cglib:cglib
        javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a [multi module project](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/) like you would do in maven with a parent pom.

In order to manage the dependency in the parent, I use the [spring dependency management plugin](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin).

You parent `build.gradle` would look like:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    check.dependsOn dependencyCheckAggregate

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        // other repos
    }

    dependencyManagement {

        def jacksonVersion = "2.+"

        dependencies {
            dependency "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:$jacksonVersion"
            dependency "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$jacksonVersion"
            dependency "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$jacksonVersion"
            dependency "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:$jacksonVersion"
            dependency "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:$jacksonVersion"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can add dependencies to your submodules without specifying version.

Comment: It looks like the multi module project must be in one common folder. Can I do this across different repositories? e.g. to refer to a template or parent in artifactory/maven jar or in git repository?

Comment: oh, actually the gradle multiproject doesn't do the dependency management. i had checked https://guides.grails.org/grails-multi-project-build/guide/index.html before and it just includes the whole parent config with bunch of `if`s...

Comment: 1. Yes, multi module projects must be in one common folder
2. The dependency management is done by the spring dependency plugin and not by gradle itself.

When working in a micro service environment, I prefer to keep the dependency management independent, since that's one of the main idea of micro services - having independent deployment artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve what you want by using Gradle's default `apply from: 'other.gradle'`, so no additional plugins are needed.

In my micro-service project I'm using something like that:

**common-gradle/env.gradle**

```
apply plugin:'groovy'

ext.compile = [ 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.1', 'cglib:cglib:3.2.9` ]
ext.testCompile = [ 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5' ]
```

**common-gradle/dependencies.gradle**

```
dependencies {
  compile ext.compile
  testCompile ext.testCompile
}
```

And the usage

**service_a/build.gradle**

```
apply from:'../common-gradle/env.gradle'

ext.compile << 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'

apply from:'../common-gradle/dependencies.gradle'
```

Thus each of my `build.gradle` files contain only 3-5 lines of critical information like project name and version.

You don't need to import the `common-gradle` as a project in your IDE, you can simply use symlinks to avoid using external references. Also during build on a Jenkins-like pipeline, the only thing you have to do is to check out the `common-gradle` repo into your working dir.